# Can't write in csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I try to write the information in the csv file, error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sizeer.py", line 68, in <module> 
     writer.writerow([name,color,price])                     
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxies = {
    "http":"http://195.189.60.97:3128", 
    "http":"http://103.78.75.165:8080",
    "http":"http://212.87.220.2:3128",
    "http":"http://88.99.134.61:8080",
    "http":"http://103.102.139.178:8080",
    "http":"http://218.60.8.83:3129",
    "http":"http://124.121.105.193:8888",
    "http":"http://198.237.114.54:8080",
    "http":"http://36.67.106.58:8080",
    "http":"http://35.214.241.28:3128"
}

base_url = ...
page = requests.get(base_url, proxies=proxies)

if page.status_code != 200:
    exit("Page wasn't parsed")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

with open("result.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Product","Color","Price"])

#Get categories
category_wrapper = soup.find_all(class_="m-menu_subItem")
categories = []
for cw in category_wrapper:
    anchor = cw.find("a", recursive=False)
    categories.append(anchor['href'])

#Iterrate categories
for category in categories:
    cat_page = requests.get(base_url + category, proxies=proxies)
    cat_soup = BeautifulSoup(cat_page.content, 'lxml')
    products_wrapper = cat_soup.find(class_="b-productList")
    cat_pagination = products_wrapper.find(class_="m-pagination").find_all("span")
    max_page = [int(s) for s in cat_pagination[-1].text.split() if s.isdigit()][0]
    #Iterrate category with pagination and get products
    for i in range(1, max_page+1):
        cat_pagination_page = requests.get(base_url+category+"/?sort=default&limit=60&page="+str(i), proxies=proxies)
        cat_pagination_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(cat_pagination_page.content, 'lxml')
        product_links = cat_pagination_page_soup.find_all(class_="b-itemList_photoLink")
        for link in product_links:
            #Get product data
            product_page = requests.get(base_url+link['href'], proxies=proxies)
            product_soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page.content, 'lxml')
            #Get product variations
            variations = product_soup.find_all(class_="m-productDescr_colorItem")
            #If there are variations
            if len(variations) > 0:
                for v in variations:
                    variation_page = requests.get(base_url+v['href'], proxies=proxies)
                    variation_soup = BeautifulSoup(variation_page.content, 'lxml')
                    price = variation_soup.find(class_="s-newPrice").text.strip().split(" ")[0]
                    name = variation_soup.find(class_="m-productDescr_headline").text.strip()
                    color = v['title']
                    print(name)
                    print(color)
                    print(price)
                    print("-------------")
                    #Save in csv
                    writer.writerow([name,color,price])                 

print("SCRAPING DONE")
```

How to keep the file open through the whole script execution ? Or I have to open it every time I am adding content ? **EDIT** In fact, the file is not even created.

Comment: It should work if you can bump `for category in categories:` this for loop into the `with` context manager where you have your file open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open("result.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Product","Color","Price"])
```

The file closes at the end of the `with` block - that is the block's purpose.

You *could* put everything inside the block, but that only makes the existing problem worse: the code is reaching several levels of indents, is long and becomes difficult to understand. This is why you use *functions* to organize the code. For example, if you have the big `for` loop set in a function:

```
def do_stuff_with(categories, writer):
    for category in categories:
        # lots of logic here
        # use `writer.writerow` when needed

# Get everything else set up that doesn't need the file, first
categories = ... # do the BeautifulSoup input stuff

# then we can open the file and use the function:
with open("result.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Product","Color","Price"])
    do_stuff_with(categories, writer)
```

Once you have that working, you can probably think of ways to apply the technique further. For example, pull out the innermost logic, for handling the `variations` for a single product. Or you can have a function to handle the creation of the `categories` data, and `return` it.

Comment: Thank you! Will fix the code as soon as I get it work.  It is just raw peace of work for now.